# Display "Free" for product with price of $0.00

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I'm trying to achieve the following in magento 2.2.2

> products with the price of $ 0.00 should display the following text: "FREE" on the front-end

I've already created my custom theme and the folder of "Magento_Catalog". My question is, how can I achieve what I've described earlier?
(or better said, where can I find the phtml or php files to copy them into my custom theme and customize them?)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273844/show-free-shipping-text-instead-of-0-00/344975#344975

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can edit your theme **Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml** file and add price check there like below code updated :

```
<?php if ($block->getDisplayValue() == 0 ) { // Add 0 Price condtion ?>

<span class="price-container <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
        <?= $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayLabel() ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?= ($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>"
        data-price-type="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceType() ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPriceWrapperCss() ?>">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
    </span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?= $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayValue() ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <span>Free</span>
    <?php } ?>
```

Or you can implement this logic where ever you want.

Comment: ..you are a genius.. 2 days looking into this and you brought a simple yet effective solution... thanks.!!!!!!

Comment: glad , your issue is solved